# Function does not function correct

Tags: javascript

Hi I have this function (zetTemperatuur) here that is supposed to change the standard temperature to a desired temperature (its supposed to be a winecooler simulator). The function works fine if i set a desired temperature between 1.0 and 9.9 degrees but as soon as i put a desired temperature of 10.0 degrees and up, the function doesnt work.

```
var temperatuur = 7.2;

function openDedeur() {
    temperatuur = temperatuur + 0.9;
    document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
    console.log("U hebt de wijnkoeler geopend, de temperatuur stijgt nu met 0.9º.");
}

function countDown() {
    setInterval(function () {
        temperatuur = temperatuur - 0.2;
        document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
    }, 300000);
}

function trekAf() {
    temperatuur = temperatuur - 0.1;
    console.log("De huidige temperatuur is " + temperatuur.toFixed(1));
    document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
}

function telOp() {
    temperatuur = temperatuur + 0.1;
    console.log("De huidige temperatuur is " + temperatuur.toFixed(1));
    document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
}

function zetTemperatuur() {
    var handmatigeTemp = document.getElementById("gewenstetemperatuur").value;
    var flag = false;

    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (handmatigeTemp < temperatuur.toFixed(1)) {
            if (flag == false) {
                flag = true;
                console.log("De motor van de wijnkoeler begint te draaien en zal geleidelijk aan dalen naar de gewenste temperatuur.");
            }
            trekAf();
        } else if (handmatigeTemp > temperatuur.toFixed(1)) {
            if (flag == false) {
                flag = true;
                console.log("De motor van de wijnkoeler begint te draaien en zal geleidelijk aan stijgen naar de gewenste temperatuur.");
            }
            telOp();
        } else if (handmatigeTemp == temperatuur.toFixed(1)) {
            console.log("Uw Wijnkoeler is op de gewenste temperatuur, namelijk " + temperatuur.toFixed(1) + ". De wijnkoeler zal nu uitschakelen om energie te besparen.");
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        } else {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }, 30);
}

countDown();
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What does it do and what were you expecting it to do? A [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help

Comment: The function zetTemperatuur doesnt work. When your desired temp is lower than standard it is supposed to countdown and if the desired temp is higher it is supposed to count up

Comment: Where is `countUp()`?

Comment: Its function telOp();

Comment: When coding it is highly advisable to use names for variables and functions that are somewhat meaningful, and also in English. This would make it much easier for other parties to read and understand what is going on.

Comment: Yes that is true, but the person who will review this is Dutch, so i think the names are pretty meaningfull for him.

Comment: As it stands, without a jsFiddle and with hard to understand names, I think you will find that you will not receive as much help.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve handmatigeTemp, it is a string. The toFixed() function will return the string represenation of temperatuur.

Javascript does not convert any types when comparing two strings. So, you are comparing the two values alphabetically.

To fix this, just remove the "toFixed()" call. Javascript will convert handmatigeTemp to a number and perform the comparison properly.

```
handmatigeTemp < temperatuur
```

[Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate my point.](http://jsfiddle.net/HpJhM/)